# Why does python not allow unbound identifiers to be used as dictionary keys?

Tags: javascript, python, dictionary

In python I can use any object as a dictionary key (7, "hello", None):

e.g.

```
myDict = {}
x = someObject()
myDict[x] = "world"
```

But I cannot use an unbound identifier. To give an example of an another language where the identifier becomes a property of the object (JavaScript)

```
x = { y : "hello" };
```

Why is this use of an unbound identifier as a key not supported? Wouldn't it be simple to define this binding under the scope of the dictionary or in the enclosing scope?

Comment: .. because it is not JS ... - it also does not allow `dict.keyvalue` access to its keys - only `dict[key]` or `dict.get(..)` - Its a different concept.

Comment: In python you can't do *anything* with an unbound identifier other than bind it.

Comment: Also, not every object can be used as a dictionary key.

Comment: what objects cannot be used as a dictionary key?

Comment: @AOrona See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

Comment: I added a JavaScript tag since the currently most upvoted answer also explains how to achieve python-like behaviour in JavaScript

Comment: "In python I can use any object as a dictionary key " no, that is not true. Only *hashable objects*. Fundamentally, you are mistaking the use-case of a Javascript object with a python `dict`. They are not the same. An unbound name *isn't an object*, so it cannot be a key. Because in Javascript objects always have string "keys", the developers of the language apparently decided that it would be convenient to allow you to omit the parentheses. This was a design decision. Python *could* have done this, but it would be really strange and unexpected

Comment: So note, dictionary keys *are not properties of the dictionary object*. The equivalent of a Python `dict` in javascript is an es6 `Map` object

Answer (score 6):

In Python, the keys in object literals are expressions that are evaluated. If you try to use an unassigned variable, it gets an error just like it would in any other use of the variable.

In JavaScript, the keys in object literals are not evaluated by default. When you write

```
{j: "hello"}
```

it's treated as

```
{"j": "hello"}
```

It doesn't matter whether `j` has a value or not, it's always treated as a literal.

FYI, EcmaScript 6 added a way to evaluate the key, using square brackets. The equivalent of a Python dictionary with a variable key would be:

```
{ [j]: "hello" }
```

and this will get an error if the variable is not declared.